# Can I run a GA to optimize wavelet transform?

Tags: frequency, genetic-algorithm, wavelet

I am running a wavelet transform (cmor) to estimate damping and frequencies that exists in a signal.cmor has 2 parameters that I can change them to get more accurate results. center frequency(Fc) and bandwidth frequency(Fb). If I construct a signal with few freqs and damping then I can measure the error of my estimation(fig 2). but in actual case I have a signal and I don't know its freqs and dampings so I can't measure the error.so a friend in here suggested me to reconstruct the signal and find error by measuring the difference between the original and reconstructed signal e(t)=|x(t)−x^(t)|. 
so my question is:
Does anyone know a better function to find the error between reconstructed and original signal,rather than e(t)=|x(t)−x^(t)|.
can I use GA to search for Fb and Fc? or do you know a better search method?
[Hope this picture shows what I mean, the actual case is last one. others are for explanations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmRGk.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you don't know the error until after running the wavelet transform, but that's fine. You just run a wavelet transform for every individual the GA produces. Those individuals with lower errors are considered fitter and survive with greater probability. This may be very slow, but conceptually at least, that's the idea.

Let's define a Chromosome datatype containing an encoded pair of values, one for the frequency and another for the damping parameter. Don't worry too much about how their encoded for now, just assume it's an array of two doubles if you like. All that's important is that you have a way to get the values out of the chromosome. For now, I'll just refer to them by name, but you could represent them in binary, as an array of doubles, etc. The other member of the Chromosome type is a double storing its fitness.

We can obviously generate random frequency and damping values, so let's create say 100 random Chromosomes. We don't know how to set their fitness yet, but that's fine. Just set it to zero at first. To set the real fitness value, we're going to have to run the wavelet transform once for each of our 100 parameter settings.

```
for Chromosome chr in population
    chr.fitness = run_wavelet_transform(chr.frequency, chr.damping)
end
```

Now we have 100 possible wavelet transforms, each with a computed error, stored in our set called `population`. What's left is to select fitter members of the population, breed them, and allow the fitter members of the population and offspring to survive into the next generation.

```
while not done
    offspring = new_population()
    while count(offspring) < N
        parent1, parent2 = select_parents(population)
        child1, child2 = do_crossover(parent1, parent2)
        mutate(child1)
        mutate(child2)
        child1.fitness = run_wavelet_transform(child1.frequency, child1.damping)
        child2.fitness = run_wavelet_transform(child2.frequency, child2.damping)
        offspring.add(child1)
        offspring.add(child2)
    end while
    population = merge(population, offspring)
end while
```

There are a bunch of different ways to do the individual steps like `select_parents`, `do_crossover`, `mutate`, and `merge` here, but the basic structure of the GA stays pretty much the same. You just have to run a brand new wavelet decomposition for every new offspring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   
I don't know enough about GA and search methods. I've just edited my post to get sure that my question is clear, Look at my edit please , and help me to implement GA or another search method please. Thanks loads.

Comment: I think your friend's idea should be fine. All you need for a GA is a way to say that one solution is better than another, and it would seem that minimizing the reconstruction error is fine for that. GAs aren't the only option -- simple local search methods can be effective, and simulated annealing or tabu search as well, but the overall picture in the linked figure looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Thank you. would you explain these search method please or introduce something that I can study.

Comment: A simple random hill climber -- generate one random set of parameters. Then alter them slightly. If the modified versions have lower error than the originals, use the modified versions as the new best solution. Repeat until no improvement can be found. Simulated annealing is similar, but allows taking non-improving moves sometimes. Just google "local search" or the other terms...the algorithms are really simple and you should find lots of good information out there.